# In this price model, employment grows with higher wages. Makes no sense

Tags: mathematical-economics, wages, price-theory

Using a Sraffian price model we have that, $p=(1+r)(pA+wl)$ where ***w*** (nominal wage rate), ***r*** (average profit rate) are scalars; ***p*** (market prices), ***l*** (labor input coefficients) are vectors; ***A*** (producers' goods input coefficients) is a matrix. I wanted to prove that an increase in ***w*** would lead to a decrease in ***A*** or ***l*** (i.e., ***p*** is constant because of perfect competition). For that purpose I first try to refolmulate as
$$A=\frac{p-wl(1+r)}{p(1+r)}$$     $$l=\frac{p(1-A(1+r))}{w(1+r)}$$

I take the derivates and I get,

$$\frac{\partial A}{\partial w} =- \frac{l}{p}<0$$
$$\frac{\partial l}{\partial w} =- \frac{p(1-A(1+r))}{w^{2}(1+r)}>0$$

Both results make no sense. An increase in wages should lead to an increase in machines (production goods) and a decrease in labor input. I could guess that an increase in wages would make companies invest in technological change so both A and l are reduced. I am sort of lost.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You should clearly state which variable is endogenous and which are exogenous. If you have only one relationship and two endogenous variables $(A,l)$, nothing can be said regarding comparative statics.

Comment: The implication that I find odd is that labor inputs are negative? If labor inputs are positive, then this rescales by some negative value and labor demand is decreasing in wages.

Comment: If A is a matrix(as you claim) p and l must be vectors and the equations you derived for A and l make no sense.